# Redux: local state id's and/or api uuid's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux with a REST api that uses UUID's. The usual pattern for storing state is using id's as a key for objects:

```
entities: {
  articles: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Some Article',
      author: 1
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Other Article',
      author: 1
    }
  },
  users: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Dan'
    }
  }
}
```

How would I use the UUID's from the api in this? I'd like to be able to create a new entity without having to request the UUID from the server first (for offline capabilities).

Should I:

1. Use local id's, keep the UUID in a `_id` property of the entity, and only use it when making an API request? This seems the easiest way, although it feels redundant and I will probably have to search through entities for a certain `_id` in some cases.

> ```
> entities: {
>   articles: {
>     1: {
>       _id: 'UUID',
>       title: 'Some Article',
>       author: 1
>     },
>     2: {
>       id: 'UUID',
>       title: 'Other Article',
>       author: 1
>     }
>   },
>   users: {
>     1: {
>       _id: 'UUID',
>       name: 'Dan'
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Use only UUID's from the API, and when creating a new item use a sort if temporary id until the API call is resolved? This seems the best way, although I'm not sure how I would go about changing the id's, which also feels wrong (as they're id's).

> ```
> entities: {
>   articles: {
>     'UUID': {
>       _id: 'UUID',
>       title: 'Some Article',
>       author: 'UUID'
>     },
>     'UUID': {
>       _id: 'UUID',
>       title: 'Other Article',
>       author: 'creating'
>     }
>   },
>   users: {
>     'UUID': {
>       _id: 'UUID',
>       name: 'Dan'
>     },
>     'creating': {
>       name: 'Stan'
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Do it some other way?

Comment: maybe you can generate  uuid on client , through 'node-uuid' module

Comment: @Utro That was what I thought initially, but it seems an unusual approach with some security and performance implications.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: @BenLime I'm using the method under no 2 at the moment. When the id returns from the server I replace the entity with the temporary id with the entity from the server.

Comment: @Job Well thank you. Hoped you had came up with another solution. Have the exact same situation and this seems kinda clunky. When the server-generated id eventually arrives I have to update every reference in the store to the previous local id. Additionally, I have to store a reference to the previous created local id, because I have some queue for queuing the offline actions... Maybe I have to do some more investigation on this.

Comment: @BenLime It is definitely clunky! Be sure to post an answer here if you find a great solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add it to the Redux store until the API returns a response.

In Vue, in my data for a given component I usually have two (sometimes more) root keys, one of which points to the part of my Redux store that handles the data, and the other that is usually `form` or something of that sort, and the Vue data changes due to binding.

After the user initiates the action to add the resource (`POST /resources`), and the server returns a successful response, I dispatch an action `addedResource`. And prior to that I'd dispatch something like `addingResource`, etc.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work? There shouldn't be a difference using an auto incremented, integer id field vs. a UUID. Your data normalization should still work the same way.

Comment: This would definitely work, but the reason I mentioned _"I'd like to be able to create a new entity without having to request the UUID from the server first."_, is that I need offline capabilities. This means the server could return the response much later, possibly even after the app has restarted.

Comment: Ahh I see, interesting. Have you considered storing in a separate, incomplete section of your store? Not sure the implications of doing that, I haven't run into this problem that you're having, but I'm sure someone has.